# Mobile Application Security, Bluemix, and Node.js apps

Tags: node.js, mobile, ibm-cloud

In looking at the Node.js boilerplate app you get with a Bluemix application, there is a package called IBMSecurity. It seems to imply that by merely putting some routes *after* it, those routes will require a tokenized call from your mobile app.

```
//uncomment below code to protect endpoints created afterwards by MAS
var mas = require('ibmsecurity')();
app.use(mas);
```

Is this accurate? If you read the docs here, http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/node#get-started-with-security, it says it locks down everything, not the routes after it. So it appears to be a bit unclear. If support for both is there, it should be mentioned in the docs as it makes the feature more appealing if you can pick and choose which routes are locked down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Raymond Camden, if you are asking that the doc section 
http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/node#get-started-with-security
describes method to enable application security  using authentication, then it is right.  I am reading from you question '... says it locks down everything, not the routes after it. So it appears to be a bit unclear. ...'.  I do not read anything like that in the doc.  Can you please clarify what section/paragraph you are reading that implies it locks down everything?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you - was on vacation. I looked at the docs again, and could not find the text that was misleading (imo :).

Comment: @Raymond Camden, thanks for your response and I am understanding that you are in agreement on my answer for the documentation part of your question.  For the initial part of question about the code, do you see any error/issues on using it?

Comment: Not now. Maybe I just had issues understanding it that day, but it seems a bit clearer now.